# When i apply array_key_exists funciton it doesnt return value from JSON

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP to get data from JSON and when i test the key in JSON with array_key_exists to make sure it exists it returns nothing. Here is the link to the library: https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/4T1BK1EB6DU056165?&fmt=json&api_key=zzasv56vxwkx67m9cy6apfmq
When i try to run it like this i get nothing:

```
if(array_key_exists('years[0]->year', $jfo)) {
$mds = $jfo->years[0]->year;

}else{
$mds="mds not found";
}
```

And this way it works:

```
$mds = $jfo->years[0]->year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are sure that the value will not be `NULL` when set, you would be better served with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Something like

```
if( isset($jfo->years) 
    && is_array($jfo->years) 
    && isset($jfo->years[0]->year)
){
    $mds = $jfo->years[0]->year;
}else{
    $mds = 'mds not found';
}
```

Or if you wanted to be less verbose and know for sure that `$jfo->years` will be an array.

```
$mds = isset($jfo->years[0]->year) ? $jfo->years[0]->year : 'mds not found';
```

Or if you are running php>=7 and want to be even less verbose.

```
$mds = $jfo->years[0]->year ?? 'mds not found';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't print the result from JSON. Would it help if i add entire code?